# How to duplicate PowerPoint slide with python pptx?

Tags: python, duplicates, powerpoint, slide

I need to create a presentation from a presentation that already exists.
I have to update the text by adding graphics or tables and keeping the format of a slide present in the template.
But there is no possibility to clone slides.
Has anyone found a solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not readily accomplished with `python-pptx`. You might be better off pursuing a Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) solution. That needs to run in a Windows environment, but gives broad control the the PowerPoint application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866634/python-pptx-copy-slide

Comment: Yes, if you're willing to dive into internals, you can accomplish most things that have no API support.