# Split ppt slides and save separately using python

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I have .pptx file having 5 slides, I want to get each slide of ppt and save each slide in a separate ppt file using python. I have tried to do this using python-pptx but I was unable to get paste option for copied side by referring [Python-pptx: copy slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866634/python-pptx-copy-slide) link. I don't want use win32 method as I am working in Linux.

Comment: As an alternative approach, consider making 5 copies of the file, then deleting the unwanted slides in each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Aspose.Slides for Python via .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/python-net/), you will easily split presentation slides and save them separately. The following code example shows you how to do this:

```py
import aspose.slides as slides

with slides.Presentation('example.pptx') as presentation:
    for i in range(len(presentation.slides)):
        with slides.Presentation() as newPresentation:
            size = presentation.slide_size.size
            newPresentation.slide_size.set_size(size.width, size.height, slides.SlideSizeScaleType.DO_NOT_SCALE)
            newPresentation.slides.remove_at(0)
            newPresentation.slides.add_clone(presentation.slides[i])
            newPresentation.save(f'slide_{i + 1}.pptx', slides.export.SaveFormat.PPTX)
```

You can also evaluate [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for Python](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/python/) for presentation manipulating. This REST-based API allows you to make 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing. The following code example demonstrates how to do the same with Aspose.Slides Cloud:

```py
import asposeslidescloud

from asposeslidescloud.configuration import Configuration
from asposeslidescloud.apis.slides_api import SlidesApi

configuration = Configuration()
configuration.app_sid = 'myClientId'
configuration.app_key = 'myClientKey'

slidesApi = SlidesApi(configuration)
response = slidesApi.split('example.pptx', None, 'pptx')
```

Sometimes it is necessary to split a presentation without any code. [Aspose Online Splitter](https://products.aspose.app/slides/splitter) can help you with this.

I work at Aspose.